# Top 10 records in MDX

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

How to get top 10 records from below query? This query is throwing Out of Memory exception.

```
SELECT 
  [Build].[Build ID] ON 0
 ,
    [Build].[Build Definition Name].MEMBERS*
    [Build].[Build].MEMBERS*
    [Build].[Build Start Time].MEMBERS*
    [Build Status].[Build Status] ON 1
FROM Build
```

Comment: Please learn to format your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the same as Sourav's answer but slightly simpler without the creation of the custom set:

```
SELECT 
  [Build].[Build ID] ON 0
 ,TopCount
  (
      [Build].[Build Definition Name].MEMBERS*
      [Build].[Build].MEMBERS*
      [Build].[Build Start Time].MEMBERS*
      [Build Status].[Build Status]
   ,10
  ) ON 1
FROM Build;
```

I've just tested against `AdvWrks` as I'm interested in your error message.

This script takes 11 seconds on my machine with a warm cache:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Internet Order Quantity] ON 0,
NON EMPTY

[Date].[Date].MEMBERS
*
[Product].[Subcategory].MEMBERS
*
[Geography].[Country].MEMBERS
*
[Customer].[Gender].MEMBERS

ON 1
FROM
[Adventure Works]
```

Whereas this is instantaneous:

```
SELECT [Measures].[Internet Order Quantity] ON 0,
NON EMPTY
TOPCOUNT(
  [Date].[Date].MEMBERS
  *
  [Product].[Subcategory].MEMBERS
  *
  [Geography].[Country].MEMBERS
  *
  [Customer].[Gender].MEMBERS
, 10
)
ON 1
FROM
[Adventure Works]
```

Your error is probably because it is trying to return and render a very big table in your results panel.

Comment: So it is just like SQL Server where adding a top clause renders results faster(unless there is an order by clause). Also I am guessing had there have been a numeric expression with TopCount, it would have been slower.

Answer (score 1):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144792.aspx), you get the top-N values using `TOPCOUNT` function, whose definition is

```
TopCount(Set_Expression,Count [ ,Numeric_Expression ] )
```

You want the top 10 based on *what?* In absense of any measure, it will get you the top 10 based on the default measure.

```
WITH SET TOP10BuildID
AS

TopCount(([Build].[Build ID].MEMBERS*
    [Build].[Build Definition Name].MEMBERS*
    [Build].[Build].MEMBERS*
    [Build].[Build Start Time].MEMBERS*
    [Build Status].[Build Status]),10)


SELECT 
  TOP10BuildID ON 0
  [Measures].SomeMeasure 
 ON 1
FROM [Build]
```

Comment: sourav - will it still throw the exception - or will moving the logic to a named set and wrapping in `TopCount` mean that the exception is avoided? Was the exception simply because it was attempting to put too many cells in the results panel?

Comment: Op's question is two-fold. First, the query on Top 10, which has been answered. The second part, which is the Out of memory exception, I am not too sure of because I don't know if the engine first dumps the entire data and then simply picks the top 10 OR only picks and drops the top 10 into the RAM. I am guessing the exception would be cleared.